# Pandas - Is there a way to filter data frames based on the count of items in a certain column?

Tags: python, pandas

New to programming and hoping to get some help with pandas. I'm starting with a project looking at baseball data (specifically pitch types). Is there a method I could use to exclude pitch types if they fall below a certain threshold?

For example, I was able to run a pivot based on count that gave me the follow data:

```
pitch_type count        
CH  79939    
CU  64166   
EP  49   
FC  46339   
FF  261485  
FO  36  
FS  10538   
FT  61044   
KC  15324   
KN  200 
SI  55361   
SL  127680
```

Based on the above figures, I want to exclude certain pitch types from the analysis given that the count isn't above a certain threshold (i.e 1500).

I'm using:

```
pitches_data[pitches_data["pitch_type"]<1500]
```

But get the follow error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Is there anyway this could easily be accomplished without having to manually remove each pitch type?

Thanks!

Comment: `df[df[column]<x]`

Comment: I'm getting an error because the dataset has pitch_type (i.e string) as the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can go about it like this:
Get the counts of each pitch_type:

```
pt_count = df.pitch_type.value_counts()
```

Find the types you need to remove (A threshold of 2000 for example):

```
pt_count = pt_count[pt_count<2000]
```

Then remove all the rows of these types:

```
df_new = df[~df.pitch_type.isin(list(pt_count.index))]
```

This way you can have your original dataframe, with the pitch_types with counts lower than threshold removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any clue about baseball but here is a solution for filtering dataframes with pandas.

```
df = df_new[df["column_of_df"] > 2000]
print(df_new)
```

With this method you filter the column `column_of_df`. The DataFrame `df_new` includes all entries in `column_of_df` that are greater than 2000. The same method you can use to filter for Strings. For that you have to equal the column to the wanted string.

Comment: I've tried that an updated the initial post with the error message I'm receiving

Comment: It has to look like this: ```pitches_data[pitches_data["count"]<1500]``` This is because you want the DataFrame on the column 'count' to be under 1500. In your example you tried to compare a string to an integer.

Comment: The table I had posted above was a pivot table of my dataset. The count column does not actually exist in my dataset

Comment: For me its unclear how you structured your DataFrame... wich column you want to filter for the values under 1500? It would be good when you can add a df.head to the question, so we can see the structure of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering the dataframe like:

```
pitches_data[pitches_data["count"].astype(int)<1500]
```

Comment: Would there be a way to accomplish this on the pitch_type column? The above was just a pivot table that I was able to create. Once I realized that the count of some of the pitch_type were below 1500, my idea was to exclude them from the data set.

Comment: ok if i understand you want to do something like that: pitches_data=pitches_data.groupby('pitch_type').filter(lambda x : len(x)<1500)